# How to decode Adyen onPaymentCompleted sessionData?

Tags: adyen

When paying with Adyen, I can capture the checkoutshopper edpoint response.
The response body contains 2 properties. The status and the sessionData. is it possible to decode sessionData to find more information about the transaction? I am particularly interested in finding the reference id of the payment.

https://checkoutshopper-test.adyen.com/checkoutshopper/v1/sessions/ABCDEFGHIJKL/payments?clientKey=test_ABCDEFGHIJKL

```
{
  "resultCode": "Authorised",
  "sessionData": "Ab02b4c0!BQ.....Ha"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to decode the sessionData from the front end. It is designed that way for security.

You can, however, find the reference id by going to the API Logs section of your customer Area.

Developers -> API Logs

There you can select your call and you will be able to see the reference in the response body.

You will also receive that reference Id when you perfor your session call in your backend. For example in Java ([here](https://github.com/adyen-examples/adyen-java-spring-online-payments/blob/main/src/main/java/com/adyen/checkout/api/CheckoutResource.java#L63)).

`var response = checkout.sessions(checkoutSession);`

The response here contains the reference.

[image]